# How to compile FreeTDS on FreeBSD10.0-64 in a right way

Tags: freebsd, freetds, unixodbc

When i try compile freetds-stable from source (today is a 0.91 version) with:

```
./configure --with-iodbc=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.2 --disable-libiconv
make
make install
```

i didn't find the **libtdsodbc.so** library as it was in the previous version from the original ports. There were just **.a** and **.la** extension files.

So where i can find it, or how to compile it in a right way cause the iODBC refers to **.so** library in **odbcinst.ini** config:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=freetds driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently 2 ports for FreeTDS from the FreeBSD port tree:

- `database/freetds` which is indeed quite old (v 0.64)
- `database/freetds-devel` which is more in pair with the version you are mentioning.

New versions of FreeTDS do not create a shared library (.so) since quite a while as mentioned on [FreeTDS site FAQ](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#where.is.libtds.so):

> libtds.so doesn't exist and isn't needed. Any reference to it in your linker commands can be safely removed.
>
> As of version 0.82, the TDS utility library is not built as a shared object. The static library libtds.a, is not installed by make install and is not needed by an applications that uses a client library (CT-Library, DB-Library, or ODBC). Because libtds is statically linked to the client libraries, they each now contain all the TDS functionality they need.

So now the question is what for are you needing such a new version, then how to update the client application to link to this new FreeTDS version.

If it is ODBC, there is also some hints regarding its configuration in the FreeTDS FAQ (...)

Comment: i need to link it to the chain: PHP -> FreeTDS -> unixODBC -> SQL Server 2005. Compile PHP with FreeTDS ?

Comment: oh yeah. PHP compiled it as a MSSQL module and it works. But i have a lot of code with **odbc_query**